# Do both of these modify the previous noun phrases?

Tags: phrases, participles

> "Yes," said Professor McGonagall. "And I don't suppose you're going to
>   tell me why you're here, of all places?"  "I've come to bring Harry to
>   his aunt and uncle. They're the only family **he has left** now."
>   (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

Do *he has* and *left* both modify the previous noun phrase, as an adjective clause and a participle, respectively?

Answer (score 1):

To be an adjective clause, it needs:

- To contain a subject and a verb
- To start with a relative pronoun, or a relative adverb
- To function as adjective

If the sentence is "They're the only family that he has left now." then *that he has left* is an adjective clause.
I understand the sentence as saying they are the only family he still has. I would not say that *left* modifies *they are the only family*.